# Простокваша - просто кваша?

Tags: этимология

Кислое молоко называют еще простоквашей. Слово, вроде как, говорящее. Но действительно ли оно происходит от слов "просто" и "кваша, квашня"?

Answer (score 3):

Можно предположить, что в основе слова "простокваша" лежит словосочетание "квасить + просто", способ образования слова - суффиксальное сложение, суффикс нулевой. Слово "просто" обозначает сквашивание молока без добавления специальных бактерий.

Comment: Вряд ли в момент появления слова кто-то подозревал о "специальных бактериях". "Просто" - это именно просто, без сложностей во всех отношениях. Т.е. не только без дополнительной закваски (хотя и она возможна), но и технологически. 
Кстати, далеко не всякое "кислое молоко" - простокваша.

Comment: Йогурт - кисломолочный продукт.
Ряженка - сладкомолочный.
По теме больше сказать нечего.

Comment: Про ряженку можно, это кислое топленое молоко, темно рыжего цвета или бурого. Цвет зависит от времени томления молока и степени выпаривания. Также и варенцом называют. Квасят добавлением сметаны или сливок не магазинных. 
йогурт современный--магазинный-добавляют сахар и фрукты. Раньше не добавляли.
аналог кефира и простокваши, но разные культуры закваски.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы не загромождать комментарии.

> > Также и варенцом называют.

[[@fatyalink](/users/1931/fatyalink)](/users/1931/fatyalink), как и с творогом-сыром, вы опять глубоко неправы.

Варенец - не ряженка. Процесс брожения другой. Варенец заквашивается смешанным молочно-спиртовым брожением, что делает его ближе к кумысу.

Ряженку относят к кисломолочным продуктам по причине использования самого процесса брожения, но готовится она из молока сладкого, топленого.

Почитайте Похлебкина что ли... Хоть и не велик авторитет, но все-таки про молоко писал хорошо.

Comment: А вы его побольше читайте, великого компилятора. Цитирую.

Если горячее топленое молоко заправить густыми свежими сливками из расчета 0,5—1 стакан сливок на каждый литр молока, то получится сладко-молочный напиток своеобразного вкуса под названием «сибирский варенец».
Варенец употребляют как прибавку к чаю, кофе, вкус которых он делает богаче, своеобразнее."


"Ряженка или украинский варенец
Если в топленое молоко влить один стакан сметаны на 1 литр молока, то получится после заквашивания в течение 3—4 часов ряженка, или украинский варенец."

 И не сладкая....за три часа и бухать можно?

Comment: да и вообще, топленое молоко - сладкое?
Чей - то не заметил, вкусное, да. А какого рожна оно после разбавления сметаной или сливками еще слаще станет?
Опыт сами поставьте, а потом других учите.
Ваш Похлебкин сгущенкой объелся, вареной.

Comment: Да, и еще, чтоб ясно было.  Варенец вообще-то передержанное в печи топленое молоко, упаренное до невозможности почти на треть, вареное.  Оттуда и название пошло. Цвет другой--совсем бурый. 
Топленое молоко закрывали крышкой, не выпаривали, или оно томилось под толстым слоем топленого масла с корочкой и НЕ КИПЕЛО. Но сливки сначала обычно раньше снимали, ценный продукт, потому и крышка,как замена.
 То есть сладости от имеющихся углеводов не прибавлялось, наоборот, процесс карамелизации углеводов сладость уменьшал.
Выпаривание несколько увеличивало процент углеводов.

Comment: >Да, и еще, чтоб ясно было.  
  
Мне давно все ясно. Варенец и ряженка - два разных продукта. Есть возражения по сути?

Топленое молоко естественно продукт сладкомолочный. Это профессиональный жаргон. "Замечать" что-то тут не обязательно.
Все что не относится к кисломолочным - сладкомолочные.
http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc_pohlebkin/37/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5

Остальное у вас - просто хамство чистой воды. Здесь не принято обсуждать, кто сгущенуой объелся. Еще раз такое себе позволите - буду удалять к чертовой матери.